# DATEDIFF in DB2 query

Tags: sql, db2, datediff

I have a query from mysql that has been running on a table I recently migrated to DB2.

The query now fails on DB2 due to the line below, saying that DATEDIFF cannot be found. I'm assuming only because this isn't a valid function on db2.

Is there an equivalent to this on DB2 that will maintain performance as well as function?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LEAST(180, DATEDIFF(curdate(), start_date)) as days
FROM table2
where expire_date > curdate()
```

Comment: Have you even looked up date/time functions in DB2? This may help: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html

Comment: I have and I did see TIMESTAMPDIFF, but I haven't seen how I can apply it similarly to use the LEAST function. I'm using it to either return number of days if the date is within 180 days back from today, but if it's more then I'm just returning 180.

Comment: "Fun with dates and times". Fun in 2003 maybe. If you are on Db2 11.1  (i.e. Db2 LUW) there are a whole bunch of date functions.  See the entry "New built-in aggregate and scalar functions." here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.wn.doc/doc/c0054107.html   notably 'DAYS_BETWEEN`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use the `DAYS()` function to convert the dates to numeric sequential numbers and then just subtract them, as in:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LEAST(180, DAYS(curdate()) - DAYS(start_date)) as days
FROM table2
where expire_date > curdate()
```

According to DB2's manual, `DAYS()` returns: "The result is 1 more than the number of days from January 1, 0001".

Answer (score 1):

On Db2 11.1 (for Linux, Unix and Windows) and above, this will work

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LEAST(180, DAYS_BETWEEN(current_date, start_date)) as days
FROM table2
where expire_date > current_date
```