# My sql statement is not processing dates correctly in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

My query is returning weird results for the variable derived from the dates (lngth_srvc). I think something is being treated as characters and the output I'm getting is the difference between character representations.

```
WITH core AS 
        (SELECT t.* 
         FROM   mhaods.stushh t 
         WHERE  stus_cd IN ( 'DWRT', 'FINL', 'DWFL', 'DWR', 
                             'DWSR', 'DWPC' ) 
                AND stdt BETWEEN '2017-02-28' AND '2019-02-28' 
         UNION 
         SELECT g.* 
         FROM   mhaods.stusha g 
         WHERE  stus_cd IN ( 'DWRT', 'FINL', 'DWFL', 'DWR', 
                             'DWSR', 'DWPC' ) 
                AND stdt BETWEEN '2017-02-28' AND '2019-02-28'), 
     core1a AS
        (SELECT p.*, 
                ROW_NUMBER() 
                  OVER( 
                    PARTITION BY asgnd_to_pin 
                    ORDER BY stdt asc) AS RANK 
         FROM   core p), 
     core1 AS
        (SELECT asgnd_to_pin, 
                stus_cd, 
                stdt, 
                RANK, 
                ( ( '2019-02-28' - stdt ) / 365 ) AS lngth_srvc_yrs, 
                (( '2019-02-28' - stdt ))         AS lngth_srvc_days 
         FROM   core1a 
         WHERE  RANK = 1 
                AND asgnd_to_pin IN ( '788387' ) 
         ORDER  BY stdt) 
SELECT asgnd_to_pin, 
       stdt, 
       lngth_srvc_yrs, 
       lngth_srvc_days 
FROM   core1 
ORDER  BY lngth_srvc_yrs 
FETCH first 20 ROWS only;
```

Sample output follows. It has 30+ years from 3/3/2017 to 2/28/2019 and 11125 days.

```
ASGND_TO_PIN            STDT    LNGTH_SRVC_YRS  LNGTH_SRVC_DAYS
      788387    3/3/2017    30.4794520            11125
      259399    3/2/2017    30.4821917            11126
      155851    3/2/2017    30.4821917            11126
      304527    3/2/2017    30.4821917            11126
      881853    3/1/2017    30.4849315            11127
      144362    3/1/2017    30.4849315            11127
      271562    2/28/2017   54.7945205            20000
      618426    2/28/2017   54.7945205            20000
```

I also tried the code with

```
((DATE('2019-02-28')-DATE(stdt))) as lngth_srvc_days
```

and still got bad results

Comment: See if this helps... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52875513/datediff-in-db2-query,  Also, I think you should define the parameters as date variables. And is `STDT` a date data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference in days between 2 dates (returns 5):

```
values days(date('2019-03-10')) - days(date('2019-03-05'))
```

Do not use `STDT BETWEEN '2017-02-28' AND '2019-02-28'`.
Use `STDT BETWEEN date('2017-02-28') AND date('2019-02-28')` instead.

Comment: Hey Mark, what are the potential problems with my method?

Comment: Unwanted string comparison instead of date one.

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting one date from another in Db2 results in a **duration** which is an decimal number representing YYYYMMDD.

So date('2017-02-28') - date('2019-02-28') = 2000, 2 years, 00 months, 00 days...

More information here [Db2 Date Arithmetic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_datearithmetic.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Db2 for LUW V11.1, some scalar functions were added to the arsenal, including DAYS_BETWEEN(first-datetime-expression, second-datetime-expression), MONTHS_BETWEEN, HOURS_BETWEEN, and others of similar kind.